# Django meta unique_together on recursive models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I declared a recursive model as shown below. How do I modify or add another unique_together Meta so that the recursiveA field cannot contain an already existing name and marker combination?

Example if name = 'a' AND marker = 'b' then recursiveA.name != 'a' AND recursiveA.marker != 'b'

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    marker = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    recursiveA = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'marker')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `save` method:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    marker = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    recursiveA = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'marker')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = self.pk is not None
        if is_new:
            assert self.name != self.recursiveA.name and self.marker ! = self.recursiveA.marker
        return super().saver(*args, **kwargs)
```